# Reading Multiple Cursor output using Spring Batch StoredProcedureItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I have a stored procedure that has 2 Cursors in Output. Is it possible to have 2 RefCursorPosition in the StoredProcedureItemReader?

Sample SP:

---

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_POC ( p_id    IN NUMBER
                                    ,p_out_c1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                                    ,p_out_c2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                                    )
IS
cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    cnt := p_id;
    OPEN p_out_c1 FOR
    SELECT level id , 
          'ABC' || level Name
    FROM dual 
    connect by level <5;
    OPEN p_out_c2 FOR
    select a.id, 
    b.name,
    b.code
    from 
    (SELECT level id , 'ABC' || level Name
    FROM dual 
    connect by level <5 )a, 
    (SELECT level id , 'ABC' || level Name , 'XYZ-' || level code
    FROM dual 
    connect by level <5)b 
    order by 2; 
END;
```

---

Reader:

---

```
public StoredProcedureItemReader spReader() {
        StoredProcedureItemReader reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader();
        SqlParameter[] parameters = {new SqlParameter("@p_id", OracleTypes.NUMBER)
                , new SqlOutParameter("@p_out_c1", OracleTypes.CURSOR)
                , new SqlOutParameter("@p_out_c2", OracleTypes.CURSOR)
        };
        
        parameters.add(new SqlOutParameter("p_out_c2", OracleTypes.CURSOR));*/
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setProcedureName("SP_POC");
        reader.setRowMapper(new SPRowMapper());
        reader.setRefCursorPosition(3);
        reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new MyItemPreparedStatementSetter());
        reader.setParameters(parameters);
        reader.setSaveState(false);
        return reader;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have 2 RefCursorPosition in the StoredProcedureItemReader?

No, that is no possible. The `StoredProcedureItemReader` is not suitable to your case with a procedure that has 2 cursors as output. You need a custom reader for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. Any reference to such customr reader using StoreProcedureItemReader?

Comment: No, unfortunately. You can always create one that is specific to your needs.